# I can't find the dependencies for Screem

Tags: 16.04, dependencies, html

I have been trying to install Screem html editor and there are some dependencies that I couldn't find.

```
No package 'libgtkhtml-2.0' found
No package 'libgnomeprint-2.2' found
No package 'libgnomeprintui-2.2' found
No package 'gtksourceview-1.0' found
No package 'libgnome-menu' found
```

I have been searching everywhere for them but couldn't find them in the `apt-cache` or online. Can anybody help me get them installed?

Comment: Which Ubuntu release are you using ? Looking at the homepage of Screem it looks really old. Copyright 2005. The Screem forums newest postings are from 2010.  Did you have a look at Bluefish html editor ?

Comment: I have looked at bluefish and didn't like it. I'm using 16.04

Comment: Okay, did you try Atom ? https://atom.io/  It is actively developed, and has many syntax options.

Comment: How did you try to install the software?

Comment: [Sublime Text](https://www.sublimetext.com/3) is another useful, highly customizable text editor that may fit your requirements.

Comment: I forgot about this question. I am using atom now but thank you. (albert if you see this, put your answer down below and I can mark this question as answered)